# How to know server's IP address where jenkins deploys and builds code

Tags: jenkins, docker

Our jenkins deploys/builds code in a docker container. Every time Jenkins deploys code, it does so in different instance of docker container. How do I know IP address of that container along with port id? Immediately after deployment I want to run my Build Validation test against the application residing in that docker container.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `-p` in docker run and then use `docker inspect` to grab the port:

```
docker run -d -p 80 --name app crramirez/limesurvey
export THEPORT=`docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "80/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' app`
```

Then you call your application: `wget http://localhost:${THEPORT}`

All of this is necessary if you have many containers running concurrently. But if you only deploy one container at time. You only need to delete the previous container and do a `docker run -d -p 80:80` call your application using your port `wget http://localhost:80`

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, I think the above code snippet gives only port ID but I need full IP address to run my Build Validation test to run against. How do I get full IP address?

Comment: Hello the address is always `localhost`, or the IP of the server which is launching the container